# Yii2 Submiting form starts downloading view file

Tags: php, forms, yii2, submit

I have a simple `yii2` form on a page called `bestellungadmin.php`
If i click the submit button, the data does not submitted, it starts downloading a file named `bestellungadmin`

**The browser console prints the message:**

```
jquery.js?v=1556869380:7841 Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/x-httpd-php: "https://rueckschlag.com/bestellungadmin?ID=101".
```

I have lots of the same forms on other sites of the project, all are working just this one not.

my controller:

```php
public function actionBestellungadmin(){
        if(Yii::$app->user->isGuest){
            return $this->goHome();
        }else if(Yii::$app->user->identity->getAdmin()){
            $model= new Bestellung();
            $model->load(Yii::$app->request->get());
            if($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())){
                $model->updateBestellung();
                Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'Bestellung erfolgreich aktuallisiert.');
                return $this->redirect('bestellungenoffen');
            }else if(Yii::$app->request->get('ID')){

                        $ID = Yii::$app->request->get('ID');
                        $query = new Query;
                        // compose the query
                        $query->select('*')
                                ->from('bestellung')
                                ->where("ID = '$ID'");
                        // build and execute the query
                        $row = $query->all();                       
                        return $this->render('bestellungadmin', ['model'=>$model, 'output'=>$row]);
            }else{
                return $this->render('bestellungenoffen');
            }
        }else{
            return $this->goHome();
        }
    }
```

my form:

```php
<?php 
                foreach($output as $row){
                    echo "<div class='row artikelAdmin'>";
                $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options'=>['enctype'=>'multipart/form-data']]); 

                echo $form->field($model, 'Nummer')->textInput(['readonly' => true, 'value' => $row['Nummer']]);
                echo $form->field($model, 'Datum')->textInput(['readonly' => true, 'value' => $row['Datum']]);
                echo $form->field($model, 'Artikel')->textInput(['readonly' => false, 'value' => $row['Artikel']]);
                echo "<a href='".$row['Rechnung']."'>Rechnung</a>";
                echo $form->field($model, 'Anmerkung')->textArea(['readonly' => true, 'value' => $row['Anmerkung']]) ;
                echo $form->field($model, 'Email')->textInput(['readonly' => false, 'value' => $row['Email']]) ;
                echo $form->field($model, 'Adresse')->textInput(['readonly' => false, 'value' => $row['Adresse']]) ;
                echo $form->field($model, 'PreisArtikel')->textInput(['readonly' => false, 'value' => $row['PreisArtikel']]) ;
                echo $form->field($model, 'PreisGesamt')->textInput(['readonly' => false, 'value' => $row['PreisGesamt']]) ;
                echo $form->field($model, 'Status')->dropDownList(['Storniert' => 'Storniert','Warten auf Zahlungseingang'=> 'Warten auf Zahlungseingang', 'Zahlung erhalten, Versandvorbereitung' => 'Zahlung erhalten, Versandvorbereitung', 'Bestellung verschickt' => 'Bestellung verschickt'],['options'=>[$row['Status']=>['Selected'=>true]]])->label('Status Ändern');
                echo $form->field($model, 'Nachricht')->textArea(['readonly' => false]) ;
                echo "<div class='form-group'>";
                echo Html::submitButton("speichern", ['class' => 'btn btn-primary ', 'name' => 'speichern']) ;
                echo "</div>";
                ActiveForm::end(); 
                echo "</div>";
                }
                ?>
```

Comment: are you using default form submit or ajax ? also what version of jquery are you using

Answer (score 0):

Remove the enctype from the form options. (You don’t need to specify any enctype options - Yii will use the default).

Multiform is used for uploads, hence your issue.

**Other comments:** 
Your action clearly uses the variable $ID, so this should be specified in the function as follows:

```
public function actionBestelling($id = null){
```

Doing this will automatically populate $id for you making it easier to code.

$row can be re-written as:

```
$row = Bestellung::findAll([‘id’=>$id]);
```

This presumes that there are multiple rows with the same ID... which is odd. If that is not the case, then use:

```
$row = Bestellung::findOne($id);
```

If there is indeed only one ID, then you can also remove the foreach statement in the view file.

Comment: Thank you very much. I changed this and now it is working! I just can't rewrite $row = Bestellung::findOne($id); because bei Model Bestellung still extends the model Model.